# Div container not expanding - please help newbie

Tags: html, containers

web page is http://www.naifaraleigh.com/template2.php 
css is http://www.naifaraleigh.com/layerstyle.css

I so much want this to work, to learn how to do this, but I am beginning to hate CSS and think that tables are not a bad thing after all! grins! Just kidding!

everything is contained in the div called container

I have managed to make the main content div slightly off center and rounded corners in white_back

I have managed to put in an absolute div to the right containing nav and logo

But I simply cannot, whatever I try, get the white_back div to stretch downwards to envelop the content of the web page.

Please please help, stop me turning back to the "Dark Side" of tabular layouts!

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the relevant code within the question; links don't work very well and for the most part, people are not inclined to start digging through the entire thing. Try to show just the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: ... Works for me?  Chrome seems to render it just fine.

Comment: I was using FireFox and didn't try Chrome. @DragonWraith - thanks for that advice, I will definitely include coding next time and my apologies

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `#white_back{height:auto;}` ???

Why do you have `#white_back{height: 458px;}` if you want it to stretch downwards?

Comment: Perhaps min-height is what they were going for?

Comment: ahhh! Is that what I am doing wrong! I couild not for the life of me see that! I changed it and it worked!